# Unable to boot after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I tried to upgrade to 20.04 using the software updater but it failed. Later when I upgraded the software on the device using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it automatically upgraded to 20.04. Now it shows these two errors when booting: `failed to listen on udev control socket` and `failed to listen on kernel control socket`

Does not complete booting process.
My machine is a Dell Inspiron 5500 series if that helps.
error on booting the Ubuntu after upgrading after 18.04 to 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only fix I could find was to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 from a live CD. Download Ubuntu 20.04, burn it to a CD or flash drive and boot from it. Then take a back up of everything and install the OS. The live CD will detect that Ubuntu is already installed and will show you three options Reinstall, install alongside current OS, remove everything and install. Choose Reinstall. If it is possible, the installer will do that otherwise, the installer will inform you of the problem and will ask what to do. Choose as per your situation.

Comment: I did the same procedure and it works for me !

Comment: Does it safe?, will it remove all of the current data on the 18.04?

Comment: @Tri Like I mentioned, you will have to take a backup of all that you want to save. It will remove all data on 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have some serious setups is my system. I cannot loose my data. Is there any way where I can boot without effecting my data.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1277029)